# Exportar BD MySQL a Excel separando tablas en distintas hojas

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpmyadmin, exportar

Tengo mi base de datos en `MySQL` con varias tablas. Debo crear algo como un metodo de exportacion en `PHP` para realizar estudios... como sea, se que en `PHPMyAdmin` se puede exportar la base de datos como CSV para Excel, pero todo en una sola hoja. ¿Hay una forma de separar las tablas en hojas distintas?
Tal cual lo que pasa al exportar con el siguiente metodo, el problema con esto es que no lleva los nombres de los campos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hay una manera de hacer lo que necesitas, más sin embargo no es exportar desde phpAdmin hacia Excel, si no lo contrario, debe de ser Importar desde Excel tabla por tabla en hojas a tu gusto de Mysql, para hacer esto debes tener lo siguiente instalado en tu máquina.

1. NET Framework 4.0.
2. Microsoft Office Excel 2007 o superior, para
3. Microsoft Windows.    .Visual Studio Tools para Office 4.0,  MySQL
   Installer puede instalar esto por usted.

y una conexión de servidor MySQL disponible.

Una vez que tengas lo necesario, abres el excel.

1.Te vas a la pestaña de **Data o Datos** y luego eligiendo el icono de la base de datos 
 **MySQL para Excel**. Esto abre una nueva barra lateral de Excel con las opciones disponibles de MySQL para Excel. La barra de navegación con el icono de MySQL para Excel se muestra en la siguiente captura de pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes seguir el procedimiento tal y como lo indica en la [página](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/exporting-and-importing-data-between-mysql-and-microsoft-excel.php).

Comment: Entiendo, pero la idea es tener un excel con toda la base de datos para que alguien mas realice estudios con los datos, no busco que pueda editar la informacion ni nada, solo que la vea en este entorno(excel).

Comment: Hola @Krieger creo que no has entendido, cuando la data se importe en excel, solo debes de compartir el mismo archivo hacia tu analizador (a), pero en ningún momento cuando el analizador (a) haga cambios en el excel se manda los cambios a la bd. No se si me dí a entender, Ahora si no quieres que se haga cambios en el excel pues solo exportas la data a PDF o bloqueas el excel.